# getting the element's id from on click with (this)

Tags: javascript, jquery

To initiate the onclick event, I have this

```
 [].forEach.call(btnAddVendorDropDown, (btnAddVendorDropDown) => {
  btnAddVendorDropDown.addEventListener('click', onAddVendorDropDownClick, false);
 });
```

The function is

```
function onAddVendorDropDownClick(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    addNewClass(modal, 'is-active');
    addNewClass(modalAddVendorDropDown, 'is-active');

    const test = $(this).attr('id');
    console.log(test);
    return test;
}
```

So what I'm trying to do is when a user clicks `btnAddVendorDropDown`, the function `onAddVendorDropDownClick` is called. I need to grab the id from the element. When I do `console.log` of the element attribute `id` from inside the function, I get exactly what I need. The problem I'm running into is when I try to grab it from outside the function, I keep getting `undefined`. I don't understand how I can grab the id once it calls this function from outside this function.

I tried this

```
var num = onAddVendorDropDownClick(); 
console.log("the function return is " + num);
```

Which is what shows `undefined`.

Comment: You're using a very strange mix of vanilla JS and jquery.

Comment: You can get the id by just doing `this.id`; no need to wrap in jQuery.

Comment: You could do `var num = onAddVendorDropDownClick.call(btnAddVendorDropDown);`, but I think you're trying to do too much with one function.

Comment: what exactly are you wanting to do from outside the event handler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this` is related directly to the caller's scope. This means that without "binding" a scope to your event handler, `this` is going to refer to your main application scope, and not the scope that jquery passes as you chain functions.

You can either wrap the event object's `target`:

```
function onClickHandler(e) {
    $(e.target).attr('id');
}
```

Or you can use `$(this)` within the jquery context of a click handler:

$('#my-button').on('click', function(e) {
    $(this).attr('id');
});

The last example works because it is occurring inside a JQuery closure, so it retains the scope from the previous function. Outside of a closure, `this` means something else.

Comment: this can be misleading though since target can be a child of the element you want the id from

Comment: True, but wrapping the target lets you do easy jquery DOM traversal to find the parent if needed.

Comment: This doesn't really answer why the OP is getting `undefined` when calling the function outside of the click event handler.

Comment: Updated my answer to be more clear about closures and scope.

Answer (score 0):

`$(this)` is JQuery context, and you are inside javascript function. You can change the click button to JQuery to use it:

```js
var test; 
$("button").click(function(){
    test = $(this).attr('id');
    console.log(test);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btnTeste">
  Teste
  </button>
```